# how to subscribe SNS topic from FE side (Angular)

Tags: angular, webhooks, amazon-sns

I'm using AWS step function. At the end of the workflow, I'd like to notify the end-user once the process is complete. Currently, I have SNS to send out an email but it means the user needs to leave the app to check. Thus, I'm exploring A2A style messaging, instead of A2P like email/SMS etc.

The frontend is using Angular. I see there is some example of Slack/Teams webhook via lambda. So, SNS -> Lambda, then Lambda send a message to the webhook enpdoint.

But, what about the custom app case? I can't locate how to create a webhook in the custom app (esp. Angular)

Comment: Not sure if you ever found an answer here, but I'm curious if you solved the problem in some way

Comment: No, I wasn't able to, although there should be a way...or someone already did this.